# Select specific parts of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to extract specific parts of a string, that could be any anywhere within the string.

```
07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER
```

For example, here's a description with multiple ranges of years.  I need to extract `07-16`, `07-10`, `08-16`, and `09-16`.  I have code to extract `07-16`, but i'm starting to get lost in the code at this point trying to figure out how to 
extract them.  I also need to get the model to compare with the model in our database, but a lot of the descriptions have small inconsistencies in them

for example: `Ford F-150, F-250... Ford F 150, F 250.. Ford F150, F250.. etc.`

`F-150` would be the correct value stored in the database to compare with.

Here is a temp table script to create sample data

```
CREATE TABLE #mytable(
DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR(101) 
);
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE REAR FLOORLINER GREY'  );
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('08-16 F250/F350/F350/F-450 TECHSHADE NA'      );
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('07-16 SILVERADO/SIERRA 1500/15-16 SILVERADO/SIERRA 2500/3500 5FT 9.25IN TECHLINER BLACK ');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('97-94 BLAZER FS/95-99 TAHOE 2DR/92-97 YUKON 2DR CARGO LINERS TAN');
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('66-72 MERCEDES-BENZ SE/SEL 4.5/108/109  66-73 250S/250SE/280S/300SEB/300SEL TECHSHADE '        );
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('66-70 FAIRLANE/TORINO  68-71 RANCHERO TECHSHADE   '      );
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('07-13 MINI COOPER/12-13 COUPE/ROADSTER/02-06 CLUBMAN FRONT RUBBER MATS TAN' );
INSERT INTO #mytable VALUES ('60-63 PORSCHE 356B  64-65 356C TECHSHADE ');
```

This is the code I've used so far to pull the first year range

```
SELECT Left(
            SubString(DESCRIPTION, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', DESCRIPTION), 5),
            PatIndex('%[^0-9.-]%', SubString(DESCRIPTION, PatIndex('%[0-9.-]%', DESCRIPTION), 5) + 'X')-1)
FROM #myTable
```

I'm looking for a similar outcome as demonstrable with the provided query.  I just need to isolate them, so that I can convert the years into datetime format for further comparison reasons.

```
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| rng1  | rng2  | rng3  | rng4  |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| 07-16 | 07-10 | 08-16 | 09-16 |
| 08-16 |       |       |       |
| 07-16 | 15-16 |       |       |
| 97-94 | 95-99 | 92-97 |       |
| 66-72 | 66-73 |       |       |
| 66-70 | 68-71 |       |       |
| 07-13 | 12-13 | 02-06 |       |
| 60-63 | 34-65 |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Most of the year ranges start in the beginning, there's no way to determine where the second range starts, not all of them are split with a backslash like this either `07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK`

How many different year ranges in a description is also indeterminable without knowing how many there are in each specific description.  These are actual samples i'm working with.

The most important question is, is what I'm asking for possible and how does one find a solution.

Comment: You describe lot of things, but you aren't specific describing current case and desire output. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Will every record always have exactly 4 matches, or could this vary?

Comment: `I need to extract ..` describe that as a generic rule.

Comment: there's a question below similar to this.  It looks like you need to search for / then look for mm-yy type format.  It's been pointed out that amalgamating data into strings to output them to a single field is a bad idea, unless perhaps in XML.  You might want to advertise the difficulties this causes to developers.

Comment: Your examples violate [First normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) and will be very difficult to use from a relational DB like SQL Server. Are you creating these records? Consider normalizing them first, your task will become much easier. You are getting this from another source? Contact the source to see if they can supply normalized data.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sorry everyone I needed to format my question better, i'm a noob here at stackoverflow.  Thank you for your patience

Comment: @M.B. You already said dont know how the data will be, so the chance of create a single solution are very slim. Try to fix the data entry so you get a better format. Or create multiple rules to handle each case.

Comment: Also you include your data, but you didnt include the desire output. That will help a lot in understanding what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a string splitter. Here are several great options. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings Using the StringSplit_XML you could do something like this.

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE (DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(101))

INSERT INTO @table VALUES ('07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER')

select LEFT(Item, 5) as YourResult
    , *
from @TABLE t 
cross apply dbo.SplitStrings_XML(t.Description, '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE (ID int,DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(101))
Insert Into @Table values
(1,'07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER')

SELECT A.ID
      ,A.DESCRIPTION
      ,B.Key_PS
      ,B.Key_Value
      ,SomeField1 = substring(B.Key_Value,1,5)
      ,SomeField2 = substring(B.Key_Value,6,200)
FROM @TABLE A
Cross Apply (Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.DESCRIPTION,'/')) B
```

Returns

```
ID  DESCRIPTION                                                         Key_PS    Key_Value     SomeField1  SomeField2
1   07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER  1         07-16 ACADIA  07-16       ACADIA
1   07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER  2         07-10 OUTLOOK 07-10       OUTLOOK
1   07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER  3         08-16 ENCLAVE 08-16       ENCLAVE
1   07-16 ACADIA/07-10 OUTLOOK/08-16 ENCLAVE/09-16 TRAVERSE FLOORLINER  4         09-16 TRAVERS 09-16       TRAVERSE FLOORLINER
```

The UDF if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select Key_Value = ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```